# Basic String Operations in vb.net application

Tags: vb.net

I wanted to design a vb.net program which finds the longest word from a string. With the help of other users i managed to do that and i added other string operations. Overall the program now counts the number of symbols, has word count, interval count, finds longest and shortest word and the average word size. I thought the code could help others who have the same issues with those operations like me so i posted it below.
Here is a image of the program:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcPNa.png
This is how the final code looks:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim a As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim a1 As Integer = Len(a)                 ' string size
    Dim a3 As String = a.Split(" ").Length - 1 ' interval count
    Dim a4 As String = a.Split(" ").OrderByDescending(Function(j) j.Length).FirstOrDefault  'longest word
    Dim a5 As String = a.Split(" ").OrderByDescending(Function(j) j.Length).LastOrDefault   'shortest word
    Dim a6 As String = a.Split(" ").Average(Function(j) j.Length)                           'average word count


    TextBox2.Text = a1
    TextBox4.Text = a3
    TextBox3.Text = a3 + 1      'word count is just 1 more than interval count
    TextBox5.Text = a4
    TextBox6.Text = a5
    TextBox7.Text = a6


End Sub
```

Comment: So you want to "design a vb.net" app but you want someone here to write it?

Comment: I have half-finished program which operates with a current string. It counts the string length, how many intervals are used and how many words are used. My last operation is to find the longest word and i can't do it, thats why i asked if someone would help me.

Comment: We cant help with code we cant see.  If you dont post the code you need help with, then by definition the post is too broad because this is not a code factory.

Comment: `str.Split(" "c).OrderByDescending(Function(j) j.Length).FirstOrDefault` to get the longest word vs length of longest word

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, i consider my question closed and will try to clarify my questions better next time.

Comment: Learn to do [lots and lots of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) before posting.  It will actually save you time - Google finds some 6870 posts already here using your title + `vb`

Comment: Your code helped me in one another operation. With a simple modification i managed to find the average word count. It looks like this:
str.Split(" ").Average(Function(j) j.Length)

Comment: That will give the average word length, not count.  The average count of one thing is the same as the total.  You should also turn on `Option Strict`

Comment: I wanted to say the word lenght. sorry again to waste your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not provide an solution in vb but maybe my c# implementation will give you a hint.

```
string source = "some string";
string longest = string.empty; 
foreach(string s in source.Split(' ')) {
    if (s.Length > longest.Length) {
        longest = s; 
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(longest);
```

Tip: Next Time it would be helpfull to ask more specific questions.

Comment: Thanks, i will try to be more accurate when i ask my questions.

Comment: Ok, it could be a solution to use loops in your code above. So you can interate trough all parts of the string you have just split